# Selenium not loading web page on second request

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm attempting to use a test runner (CucumberJS) to utilize selenium to run a test suite. Selenium is set up to start a new browser session with every new scenario. The world code looks like this:

```
'use strict'
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

class World {
  constructor(browser) {
    this.browser = browser
  }

  cleanUp(callback) {
    this.browser.quit().then(callback)
  }
}

exports.World = function(callback) {
  const browser = new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build()

  const timeouts = browser.manage().timeouts()
  timeouts.pageLoadTimeout(10000)
  timeouts.setScriptTimeout(5000)
  timeouts.implicitlyWait(1000)

  const world = new World(browser)

  callback(world)
}
```

Here is the step definition

```
function stepDefinitions() {
  this.World = require('../support/world').World

  this.Given(/^I am on the dashboard page for game (\d+)$/, function (id, callback) {
    this.dashboard = new Dashboard(this.browser)
    this.dashboard.viewGame(id).then(callback)
  })

  this.After(function(callback) {
    this.cleanUp(callback)
  })
}
```

I am using a scenario outline, so the above step definition is executed twice. I have only written this one step definition currently so that I write the minimum necessary code.

What is happening is this: On the first scenario outline, this works perfectly. Loads up the page, selenium terminates on it's own, brilliant. But on the second outline, selenium just boots up Chrome, does not try and load any web page at all - just hangs with `data:;` in the URL. It will do this forever until I manually close the test runner and Chrome process. Here is the selenium log:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 30263 Only local connections are allowed.
12:27:07.486 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]]
12:27:07.502 INFO - Executing: [page load wait: 10000]) 
12:27:07.502 INFO - Done: [page load wait: 10000] 
12:27:07.518 INFO - Executing: [set script timeoutt: 5000]) 
12:27:07.518 INFO - Done: [set script timeoutt: 5000] 
12:27:07.533 INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 1000]) 
12:27:07.533 INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 1000] 
12:27:07.534 INFO - Executing: [get: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/game/1]) 
12:27:11.269 INFO - Done: [get: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/game/1] 
12:27:11.308 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 77e320e2-e116-46a2-bce7-364a2fd1ad8d]) 
12:27:12.599 INFO - Done: [delete session: 77e320e2-e116-46a2-bce7-364a2fd1ad8d] 
// At this point, the first scenario is finished and the second begins
12:27:12.630 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]]) 
12:27:12.630 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}] Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 25037 Only local connections are allowed. 
12:27:14.423 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]]
```

As you can see, it only creates a new session and does nothing else. How can I proceed with this?